# Problems adding webparts to a page in the correct order

Tags: web-part, web-template, web-part-page, file, ordering

I would think there's something supersimple I'm missing, but I can't find where I'm going wrong.

I have a feature deploying a default.aspx page with two CQWP webparts. I use the [AllUsersWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms480534.aspx) method and specify WebPartZone and WebPartOrder. Even so, the webparts are deployed in seemingly random order.

Here's my relevant XML from the Elements.xml file that deploys the default.aspx page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="SectionFrontPage" Path="SectionFrontPage" Url="" >
    <File Path="default.aspx" Url="default.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" >
      <AllUsersWebPart ID="News1" WebPartZoneID="ContentLeft" WebPartOrder="0">
        <![CDATA[
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <webParts>
            <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
              <metaData>
                <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>
              <data>
                <properties>
                  <property name="Title" type="string">News from this section</property>
                </properties>
              </data>
            </webPart>
          </webParts>
        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
      <AllUsersWebPart ID="News2" WebPartZoneID="ContentLeft" WebPartOrder="1">
        <![CDATA[
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <webParts>
            <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
              <metaData>
                <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>
              <data>
                <properties>
                  <property name="Title" type="string">News from subsections</property>
                </properties>
              </data>
            </webPart>
          </webParts>
        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: umh, I have tried that sometime ago, checked it now and it looked just the same, but I didn't use the webParts tag, only webPart. Dunno if that would make any difference

Comment: Removing the webparts tag only lead to this error: Web Part Error: Cannot recognize the XML namespace of this Web Part.
Show Error Details 
Hide Error Details 
[WebPartPageUserException: Cannot recognize the XML namespace of this Web Part.]
  at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartImporter.CreateXdoc(XmlReader reader)...

Comment: I see, I'm no expert on this. But I used content editors only, the code looks roughly like this: <WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">, then I have tags for <Assembly /><TypeName /><Title /><FrameType /><Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"></Content></WebPart>

Comment: What type of web part page? Some web part page has no zone, some had 1 or 2 zone.

Answer (score 1):

For the WebPartOrder property, try to start the numbering at 1, not 0. I just did a search across the 14 hive for all uses of AllUsersWebPart, and none of them used 0. Just a guess, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have correct **WebPartZoneID**, by default it's - **Left**.

Comment: I've modified the page. *ContentLeft* is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add another web part zone and split the web parts up.

Comment: That'll work, although it's avoiding the problem, not solving it :)